# How to get Sushiswap and Uniswap prices from API for WETH/DAI on KOVAN?

Tags: uniswap, kovan, exchange-api, sushiswap

Where can I find APIs to query data of WETH/DAI Prices on Uniswap and Sushiswap? For the mainnet, there is thegraph.com where one can query price data with pre-defined GraphQL queries, but I can't find anything similar for Kovan. Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chainlink APIs to get the prices of the token pairs. However they are very limited to the Kovan testnet. Link: https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/